# ASP.NET (C#) How to set/update input value of dynamically/runtime generated inputs?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I hope someone has an idea:

**Short version:**
In ASP.NET (C#), how can I set/update a input value of a input element, which was created on runtime (via C# or JS)?

**Long version:**

I use a MasterPage Site in ASP.NET and I dynamically create some input elements on the server side (C#). Now I want to access these elements, for example to change the value after Load event or after submit.

So here are some infos:

- I want to code a website in C#
- I need to create input elements dynamically / on runtime
- After load (all elements were created) or atleast on a submit / post, I want to read SQL Data and update all input values
- I don't want to use javascript / jQuery
- I am not new to C#, but in ASP.NET, years ago I coded a lot in PHP (which was much easier by the way :D)

This is what I have so far, I have shortened the code a lot for better reading.

**backend** code of **HtmlHelper.cs**:

```cs
public string CreateInput(string elementId)
{
   string returnHtml = "<div class='many classes'><div class='more divs'><i class='icon classes'></i><input type='text' name='" + elementId + "' id='" + elementId + "' class='some classes' runat='server' /></div></div>";
}
```

**frontend** code of **users.ascx**:

```cs
<form method="post" runat="server">
   <%=html.CreateInput("txt_firstname") %>
   <input type="submit" name="change_firstname" value="Change Input Value" runat="server" onserverclick="ChangeInputValue" />
</form>
```

**backend** code of **users.ascx.cs**:

```cs
public HtmlHelper html = new HtmlHelper();

protected void ChangeInputValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // this will give me a readonly error
   Request.Form["txt_firstname"] = "Some new value...";

   // this seems to work, but the changed value is not shown in the form
   var propertyInfo = collection.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   propertyInfo.SetValue(collection, false, new object[] { });
   Request.Form["txt_firstname"] = "Some new value...";
}
```

This is what the **CreateInput** function returns (for example):

```html
<div class='many classes'>
   <div class='more divs'>
   <i class='icon classes'></i>
   <input type='text' name='txt_firstname' id='txt_firstname' class='some classes' runat="server" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I know there are other ways to add dynamic html code, like:

```cs
<div <%=div1() %> >
   <div <%=div2() %>>
   <i <%=icon() %>></i>
   <input id='txt_firstname' <%=input("txt_firstname") %>/>
   </div>
</div>
```

So I can use `txt_firstname.Value = "some new value..."`
**But** I want the complete block to be dynamic and I want to use html, because I want to use the html maybe in a php project. The other problem is: On some pages there are input elements, which are created via javascript. So the user can add a "row" to save multiple values (on each "add" click I create a new input element).
It's the same problem, the input element is generated on runtime (via JS) and c# don't know this element. In PHP I can simply use the $_POST value, no matter if it's raw html or generated via PHP.

So: How can I set/update a input value of dynamically/runtime generated inputs?
Maybe my thoughts are too complicated, but there are many websites with dynamic input fields (user added rows for example), there have to be a way to update these values on the server side, or am I wrong?

And please don't hate me for generate html code as string, I try to build my own "framework", like everyone uses a framework today, and these frameworks mostly do the same, they generate code.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC / Razor is closer to what you are used to.

Comment: I didn't look at everything but you might need to look into *page lifecycle*, esp. when to create/recreate user controls.

Comment: Razor seems close to my ideas, but you can't change the values after the load too. The outher thing is I have already much coding. I will try it with a other lifecycle, so I need to load all values BEFORE I create the HTML Output. Seems there is no other way. Thank's guys ;)